# What is wrong with this piece of code [Python]?

Tags: python

```
# For updating the version!
version = "0.1"

# For game start!
from choice1 import choice1
# insert import functions from checkpoints choices here!

def gamemenu():
print("Welcome to the RTG!")
# Starts the game
print("1. START!")
# Goes to an earlier checkpoint
print("2. CHECKPOINTS!")
# Views the "about' page
print("3. ABOUT")
# Shows my website address!
print("4. INFO ABOUT CREATOR")
# Exits the game
print("5. EXIT")

# The user input!
option = input("Make your choice, buddy! "

if option == "1":
   choice1()
# elif option == "2":
# Not added yet
elif option == "3":
   print("Random Text RPG, version %s" % version)
   print("This is just a random game made by me for fun")
   print("Please dont't take offence :(")
elif option == "4":
   print("Made by Lightning Bolt."))
elif option == "5":
   break
else:
   print("ERROR: invalid option")
   menu()

menu()
```

Hello everyone,

I am a beginning programmer and I have encountered a problem which I am inable to solve. When I run my program in the Python 3 shell it says invalid syntax and marks the ":" in line 1 red, which means that there is something wrong there. With all other if/else/ifelse statements it doesn't say that the : is invalid syntax. If I remove the ":" it marks choice1() in red for improper syntax, while it's indented with exactly 4 spaces.

I really have no idea what's wrong with the code, thanks for anyone who helps me!

here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdCa.jpg (indentation and such)

Comment: indent all the lines of code under ur function `def gamemenu():` till `print 5 exit`

Comment: Is that actually how your code looks? You have missing parens, a break without a loop and multiple indentation errors

Comment: First, you don't mean "line 1", that's a comment. You mean the "if option == "1":" line. The error there is obvious, and on the line above--you didn't close the parentehsis. Also, much of your code is not indented properly, which will cause it to fail--this is Python, indentation matters.

Comment: I've done that, but it doesnt show up in the code thing here, here is a screenshot http://imgur.com/wuWMa0L

Comment: Missing ) urgh I' m so stupid thanks lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close the parenthesis on the line that gets input from the user
2. Remove the extra parenthesis under `elif option == "4"`
3. Remove the break statement, there's no loop there

Code:

```
# For updating the version!
version = "0.1"

# For game start!
from choice1 import choice1
# insert import functions from checkpoints choices here!

def gamemenu():
    print("Welcome to the RTG!")
    # Starts the game
    print("1. START!")
    # Goes to an earlier checkpoint
    print("2. CHECKPOINTS!")
    # Views the "about' page
    print("3. ABOUT")
    # Shows my website address!
    print("4. INFO ABOUT CREATOR")
    # Exits the game
    print("5. EXIT")

    # The user input!
    option = input("Make your choice, buddy! ") #you missed a closing parenthesis here :D

    if option == "1":
        choice1()
    # elif option == "2":
    # Not added yet
    elif option == "3":
       print("Random Text RPG, version %s" % version)
       print("This is just a random game made by me for fun")
       print("Please dont't take offence :(")
    elif option == "4":
       print("Made by Lightning Bolt.") # there was an extra paren here
    elif option == "5":
       pass #as @Padraic mentioned, there should be no break statement
    else:
       print("ERROR: invalid option")
       menu()

menu()
```